# Cycle through array of objects, find matching value and then create new array containing each set of matched values

Tags: javascript, arrays

My question may not make much sense but I'm trying to cycle through an array of objects that may or may not be referencing the same item/place.

Each place has a unique identifier so I can use that to check.

Right now I have the original array as well as a new array that is filled as the program evaluates the identifiers.

If the program hasn't already seen that identifier in the array, I'd like it to create an array within that second array and add the object to that newly created array.

If however, that identifier has been seen before, the object should be added as the next item in the array that matches.

Here is some sample data

```
[{
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0001"
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  }, {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0001"
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  },
  {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0200"
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  },
  {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0203"
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  }
]
```

The program should cycle through the array, view the id of the first object, realize it's not present in the new array and add it as an array itself containing the first object. The second object then matches that id so it's added as the second array item of the first array item in the second array.

Here is the start of my attempt

```
function findDups (arr){
    let newArray = []

    arr.forEach(function(current){
        if(newArray.indexOf(current.id) === -1){
            newArray.push([current.id{current}])
            console.log(newArray)
        }

    })

}
```

Basically, how can I dynamically add entire objects as array items within an array

Here is basically what I'm expecting arrays grouped by id:

```
newArray = [
        [0001: [{
                    boro: "MANHATTAN",
                    id: "0001"
                    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
                    dba: "abc"
                }, {
                    boro: "MANHATTAN",
                    id: "0001"
                    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
                    dba: "abc"
                }

            ]

        ],
        0200: [{
            boro: "MANHATTAN",
            id: "0200"
            date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
            dba: "abc"
        }]
        etc. etc.
    ]
```

Comment: What is your expected output from the array you provided?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me. What exactly are you trying to do with the result?

Comment: In the example above, I would expect the result to be

Comment: Can you include expected result at Question?

Comment: Are you trying to return the ids of the duplicate items or find the duplicate items them selves? Or are you trying to remove all duplicate items?

Comment: added what is expected in the question

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of `var x = oldArray[i].id; newArray.x += oldArray[i];` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** Your desired output is not a valid structue. My code generate an object!

Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a hash object of the IDs like this:

```js
function groupById(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(h, o) { // for each object o in the array arr
    if(h[o.id]) h[o.id].push(o);     // if there is already an array for the id o.id, then push this object to it
    else h[o.id] = [o];              // if not, then create an array that contain this object o
    return h;
  }, {});
}


var array = [{"boro":"MANHATTAN","id":"0001","date":"2016-10-26T00:00:00","dba":"abc"},{"boro":"MANHATTAN","id":"0001","date":"2016-10-26T00:00:00","dba":"abc"},{"boro":"MANHATTAN","id":"0200","date":"2016-10-26T00:00:00","dba":"abc"},{"boro":"MANHATTAN","id":"0203","date":"2016-10-26T00:00:00","dba":"abc"}];

console.log(groupById(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this might be what you're looking for?

```
var newArr = {};
var arr = [
  {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0001",
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  }, 
  {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0001",
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  },
  {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0200",
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  },
  {
    boro: "MANHATTAN",
    id: "0203",
    date: "2016-10-26T00:00:00",
    dba: "abc"
  }
];

function makeNewArrById (obj, i) {
  if(!newArr[obj.id]) {
    newArr[obj.id] = [];
  }

  newArr[obj.id].push(obj);
}

arr.map(makeNewArrById);

console.log(newArr);
```